# Line breaks after hard comments in Sass

Tags: compression, comments, sass

I'm using the latest Sass with Compass addon. I want my production code to include my "hard" comments, but after that I would like to have a line break.

```
/*! Generic elements and layout */
/* *********************************************** */
html
  box-sizing: border-box
...
```

Should be outputted like this:

```
/* Generic elements and layout */
html{box-sizing: border-box}...
```

Is this a possibility? I would like to include licences from 3rd party things (flexbox etc.) like this in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  This sort of thing would require a modification to Sass.  You could use the short C style comment instead to get what is functionally the same thing:

```
/*! Generic elements and layout */
// ***********************************************
html
  box-sizing: border-box
```

Comments preceded by double forward slash are never part of the generated CSS.

Comment: The ! keeps the comment in :compressed, but I would like to have a breakline after a comment in :compressed

Comment: You would still have to modify Sass to do this.  When the code is compiled to CSS, all of the whitespace, color format, curly brace placement, etc. is made uniform for that particular compression type.