# SASS: preserve comment position

Tags: sass, node-sass, rtlcss

I recently decided to use [RTLCSS](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss) to make RTL versions of my stylesheetes.
Now i'm trying to use **Declaration-level directives** to tell RTLCSS what to do, but SASS compiles my comments to next line.

For example, `font-size: 14px/*rtl:15px*/;` Compiles to

```
font-size: 14px;
/*rtl:15px*/
```

And that stops RTLCSS from procssing it properly. Is there a way around this? can i configure sass to just compile the value as-is, preserving comment position?

P.S. I use grunt-sass(node-sass) to process my scss files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Line breaks after hard comments in Sass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812933/line-breaks-after-hard-comments-in-sass)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use SASS [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) syntax, passing your comment as string

```
body{ font-size: 14px #{"/*rtl:15px*/"}; }
```

will produce

```
body { font-size: 14px /*rtl:15px*/; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Both standard /*rtl:...*/ and special/important /*!rtl:...*/ notations are supported.

You can use ***/!rtl:*** to escape from sass compiler

[Documentation](https://rtlcss.com/learn/getting-started/why-rtlcss/#processing-directives)